# salesforce url The SSL connection could not be established using c# .net code

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, salesforce

To call `salesforce api` i'm using restclient like below -

```
  var client = new RestClient("https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.Parameters.Clear();
                request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
                request.AddParameter("username", userName);
                request.AddParameter("password", password);
                request.AddParameter("client_id", clientID);
                request.AddParameter("client_secret", clientSecret);
                response = client.Execute(request);
```

but getting error -

```
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

anyone knows work around for this ?

Comment: What is the inner exception? Add a breaking please in the catch and inspect the inner.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? this is likely because your request is not using TLS 1.2

Comment: i'm using azure functions and its .net core 2.0

Comment: this is the error i'm getting into inner exception as well

Comment: I know it's 18 months later, but did you find out what was wrong here?

My code works from my development PC, but fails on the UAT server. Our networking guys tell me everything on the UAT server is up to date, but I'm guessing it's not. What do I look for to see if there is something outdated on the server? Or maybe not able to get through? The SSL certificate on the UAT server only expires next year.